# XAML namespace error for converter class

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am getting an error: The name "local:ThumbnailConverter" does not exist in the namespace using.Notes

All the files are in the namespace Notes

Converters.Cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace Notes
{
    public class ThumbnailConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var thumbnailStream = (IRandomAccessStream)value;
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(thumbnailStream);
                return image;
            }
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
        public object convertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="Notes.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Notes"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ThumbnailConverter x:Name="thumbnailConverter" />
            <DataTemplate x:Key="Custom190x130ItemTemplate">
                <Grid Width="190" Height="130">
                    <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="190" Height="130">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource thumbnailConverter}}" Width="190" Height="130"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="itemViewSource" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <GridView x:Name="itemGridView"
          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
          AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
          Grid.Row="1"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Custom190x130ItemTemplate}"
    SelectionMode="None" />


</Page>
```

and now MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage.BulkAccess;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace Notes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            //query jisse data retrieve karenge
            var filterType = new string[] { ".jpg", ".png" };
            var options = new Windows.Storage.Search.QueryOptions(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, filterType);
            options.ApplicationSearchFilter = "System.Photo.DateTaken:>System.StructuredQueryType.DateTime#LastMonth";
            var fileQuery = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);


            //creating the data source
            var fileInformationFactory = new FileInformationFactory(fileQuery,Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView,190,Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale,true);



        }
    }


}
```

Please help with the probable solutions! Thanks in advance

Comment: You should write <Page.Resources> instead of <UserControl.Resources> but maybe this is not the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to declare a namespace in XAML is the following:

```
xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace.Here"
```

So in your case, it'll look like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Notes"
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! :)

Comment: No problem :-) If this answers your question, don't forget to mark it as answered by clicking on the tick on the left hand side. Thanks.

Comment: plz answer the second question as well